# Using retrofit to return information from an API, how do I use this in other classes?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

So I have (I think) set up a way for my application to pull information from a web service. However I'm unsure how to put this information into variables/use the information in other classes?

I setup retrofit in one class:

```
public static final String URL = "baseURLhere";

public void setupRF(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

I have another class mirroring the JSON that will be returned:

```
public class Friends {
private String name;
private double lon;
private double lat;
private List<Friends> friends;
getters and setters (omitted)...
}
```

And then finally I have:

```
public interface FriendsInterface {
@GET("restofURLhere.php")
Friends getFriends();
}
```

So from what I've understood if I've done everything correctly so far then the getFriends() method should be calling the information from the API - however how do I store these into my particular variables? I'm assuming once they're stored I can just call them like regular variables in other classes/activities?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: i use dagger2 and make use of singleton pattern and then i can inject whatever module i need in activity or fragments

Comment: I'm fairly new to using these libraries so I'm not too sure what that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create singleton with your Retrofit instance. To download data call:

```
Friends friends = retrofit.createService(FriendsInterface.class).getFriends();
```

Those are basics. Read this: [1](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) [2](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) [3](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
Also consider using Retrofit ver 2, which is now stable.